# font size when using mobile does not follow

Tags: css

I just want to ask why the font-size of the event types at the back of this card seemed to be zoomed when using mobile I already set the font-size to 16, but it looks bigger than the usual 16px,
I also tried to use 15px but it seemed to be too small and unreadable. The desktop version is okay but not on mobile.I also tried 0.95em see 1st picture below vs. the 1em 2nd picture 
https://jsfiddle.net/ecbumaw9/
.

```
back .description { 
  font-size: 16px; 
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You probably have some other "mobile friendly" CSS applied to the page on small screen devices.

Comment: I don't think there's an overlap I only have one media query applied for the lists

Answer (score 1):

To make `font-size` scalable and more mobile friendly try using `em` instead of `px`.

More information on the differences between `em`, `px`, `pt` and `%` can be found [Here](https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent)

Comment: I am wondering why there is a big difference between 1em and 0.9em, the first one is too large then the latter is too small

Comment: Also the link added explains the differences.

Comment: yes, I tried I added the screenshot of the different of 0.95 em vs 1em above on the main question